# google analytics re-marketing code not validated

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

So I've added this additional line of code to our Google Analytics tracking code so it supports display and remarketing campaigns as outlined by this help article https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en

However, within analytics, it still keeps showing that it's not been added. It's definitely in there and the rest of the tracking is working fine.

I am using Universal Analytics (analytics.js) and have added that one line to the existing code as shown

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-53957342-1', 'auto');
      ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

      ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Has anyone come across the same issue?
Any tips or advice would be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: hit skip validation  http://www.daimto.com/how-to-enable-demographics-and-interest-reports-in-universal-analytics/

Comment: Is your GA tracking in the head section or at the bottom of the page? Some GA verification only searches the first # bytes of the page - I'll update this if I find the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Activation of this feature may take 48 hours. I recently did the same and added that code to my site and even after click on Validate, it would show as not active until two days later! With most things related to GA, you just need a little patience (usually). If by 48 or 60 hours later the code is still not active, then if you believe you have done everything correctly to implement it, then skip validation.

Hope this helps.